# wmic space in file path, results in No Instance(s) Available

Tags: wmi, wmic

I'm using wmic to get information on a service using the full path to a file.

```
wmic service where PathName="C:\\Windows\\system32\\CxAudMsg64.exe"
```

Which works fine.  However, when I use a path with a space in it like the following:

```
wmic service where PathName="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Adobe\\ARM\\1.0\\armsvc.exe"
```

It tells me: "No Instance(s) Available."  Which is not true because the path is correct and the service exists.   Do I need to escape the space in the path or something?

Answer (score 1):

My mistake.

```
wmic service
```

wmic service is showing PathName values are listed with qoutes sometimes and sometimes not.  You have to check for both.

```
wmic service where PathName='"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Adobe\\ARM\\1.0\\armsvc.exe"'
```

and

```
wmic service where PathName='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Adobe\\ARM\\1.0\\armsvc.exe'
```

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR -

```
wmic service where "pathname='\"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe\"' AND ServiceSpecificExitCode=0" get name

#OR....

wmic service where (pathname="\"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe\"" AND ServiceSpecificExitCode=0) get name
```

## Details -

While the other answer works for single-criterion questions, it'll error out for a compound query.  I recommend using either the "Quote Before Equals" syntax or the "Paren Around Where" syntax.  Here are some examples

#### Single-Where + Quote After Equals

```
Invalid alias verb          == wmic service where pathname=""C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe"" get name
Invalid query               == wmic service where pathname="\"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe\"" get name
Invalid alias verb          == wmic service where pathname="^"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe^"" get name
Invalid alias verb          == wmic service where pathname=^""C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe^"" get name
Invalid query               == wmic service where pathname="\"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows^ Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe\"" get name
Invalid query               == wmic service where pathname="\"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\ Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe\"" get name
Works Perfect               == wmic service where pathname='"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe"' get name
```

#### Single-Where + Quote Before Equals

```
No Instance(s) Available    == wmic service where "pathname='C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe'" get name
No Instance(s) Available    == wmic service where "pathname='^""C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe""'" get name
No Instance(s) Available    == wmic service where "pathname='""C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe""'" get name
Invalid query               == wmic service where "pathname=""C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe""" get name
Invalid alias verb          == wmic service where "pathname='^"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe^"'" get name
Invalid alias verb          == wmic service where "pathname='"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe"'" get name
No Instance(s) Available    == wmic service where "pathname=\"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows^ Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe\"" get name
No Instance(s) Available    == wmic service where "pathname=\"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe\"" get name
Invalid alias verb          == wmic service where "pathname=^"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe^"" get name
Invalid query               == wmic service where "pathname=\"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\ Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe\"" get name
Works Perfect               == wmic service where "pathname='\"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe\"'" get name
```

#### Single-Where + Paren Around Where

```
Works Perfect               == wmic service where (pathname="\"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe\"") get name
```

#### Compound-Where + Quote After Equals

```
Invalid alias verb          == wmic service where pathname='"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe"' AND ServiceSpecificExitCode=0 get name
Invalid alias verb          == wmic service where pathname='"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe"' AND ServiceSpecificExitCode='0' get name
```

#### Compound-Where + Quote Before Equals

```
Works Perfect               == wmic service where "pathname='\"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe\"' AND ServiceSpecificExitCode=0" get name
```

#### Compound-Where + Paren Around Where

```
Works Perfect               == wmic service where (pathname="\"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows Defender\\platform\\4.18.1902.2-0\\NisSrv.exe\"" AND ServiceSpecificExitCode=0) get name
```